# Algorithm to Differentiate between water and land

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, terrain

I am trying to come up with an algorithm to tell the difference between water and land. I have a 2D array holding only 0's(black squares) and 1's(grey squares), which produces this image. I colored one of the water areas blue so you can see what is supposed to be water. Water are the areas that are large and have a round shape. I colored some land areas green. All of the straight black lines are supposed to be land as well as some of the smaller round shapes.

Right now, all the black areas are represented as 0 and all grey areas as 1. So in the picture, the green and blue spots are both represented as being the same thing. I need some of the black areas(water) to be represented as 2 instead. What is a good way to do this? The best thing I came up with so far is to calculate the area of each black spot, and only allow areas above a certain threshold to be water. I think there are better ways though and am wondering what you guys think.

[image]

Comment: Step 1: set all the 0's with only 0's as neighbors to water. Step 2: set all the 0's with any water as a neighbor to water.

Comment: Probably you can use this [Flood_fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) for starting point.

Comment: Joel, I did think of the first step you said, but didn't think about the 2nd. The only thing bad about it is that it will turn small areas into water as well.(Green spot I filled in, or the small 3x3 square to the left of it)

Comment: I am going to merge both of your suggested alogorithms. I'll mark 0's that are surrounded by 3 or more 0's in each direction, and then flood fill that area.

Comment: You should probably start by establishing a more determinate condition for what is considered land and what is considered water. Saying "areas that are small" is very, very arbitrary. For example, I wouldn't be able to tell if the black region south of the westernmost edge of the blue region should be land or water.

Comment: Saying "areas that are small" ended up working out. Check the answer I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining the first two suggestions, I was able to come to a solution. I first look for water tiles that are surrounded by an arbitrary number of water tiles(i.e 4 in each direction) and then use the flood-fill algorithm to set the entire body of water to actually be water. Here is a picture of the
result. I added a coastline as well for looks. As you can see, the smaller round bodies are still land, which is exactly what I wanted.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps compare the area with the length of the edge, this may give you a measure of roundness, since perfect circles will have the highest ratio of area to edge, whereas the streets (I assume they're streets) will have a small ratio.

Perhaps also threshold both those measures.

Comment: I came up with a solution by combining the previous suggestions, but I will keep this in mind as it will be useful later on for other things I plan on doing. Thanks